# What does the regex [^\s]*? mean?

Tags: python, regex

I am starting to learn python spider to download some pictures on the web and I found the code as follows. I know some basic regex.
I knew `\.jpg` means `.jpg` and `|` means `or`. what's the meaning of `[^\s]*?` of the first line?  I am wondering why using `\s`? 
And what's the difference between the two regexes?

```
http:[^\s]*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)
http://.*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)
```

Comment: "zero or more non-whitespace characters, shortest match"

Comment: Check this out: https://regex101.com/#python Throw your regex there and it will tell you what each thing does.

Comment: Tons of tutorials out there. http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: [^\s]*? means zero or more non-whitespace characters？ @Nayuki

Comment: What's wrong with the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or the related [howto](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html)?

Comment: Seems odd that `\S*` is not used though.

Comment: @Evert This is exactly my consideration. \s means whitespace? so why using \s

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Alright, so to answer your first question, I'll break down `[^\s]*?`.

- The square brackets (`[]`) indicate a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). A character class basically means that you want to match anything in the class, at that position, one time. `[abc]` will match the strings `a`, `b`, and `c`. In this case, your character class is *negated* using the caret (`^`) at the beginning - this inverts its meaning, making it match anything *but* the characters in it.
- `\s` is fairly simple - it's a common shorthand in many regex flavours for "any whitespace character". This includes spaces, tabs, and newlines.
- `*?` is a little harder to explain. The `*` [*quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is fairly simple - it means "match this token (the character class in this case) zero or more times". The `?`, when applied to a quantifier, makes it *lazy* - it will match as little as it can, going from left to right one character at a time.

In this case, what the whole pattern snippet `[^\s]*?` means is "match any sequence of non-whitespace characters, including the empty string". As mentioned in the comments, this can more succinctly be written as `\S*?`.

To answer the second part of your question, I'll compare the two regexes you give:

```
http:[^\s]*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)
http://.*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)
```

They both start the same way: attempting to match the protocol at the beginning of a URL and the subsequent colon (`:`) character. The first then matches any string that does not contain any whitespace and ends with the specified file extensions. The second, meanwhile, will match two literal slash characters (`/`) before matching any sequence of characters followed by a valid extension.

Now, it's obvious that both patterns are meant to match a URL, but both are incorrect. The first pattern, for instance, will match strings like

```
http:foo.bar.png
http:.png
```

Both of which are invalid. Likewise, the second pattern will permit spaces, allowing stuff like this:

```
http:// .jpg
http://foo bar.png
```

Which is equally illegal in valid URLs. A better regex for this (though I caution strongly against trying to match URLs with regexes) might look like:

```
https?://\S+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)
```

In this case, it'll match URLs starting with both `http` and `https`, as well as files that end in both variations of `jpg`.

Comment: So `^\s` means matching anything except whitespace? If this is the case, then I understand the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LiuHao: If an answer is useful/correct, good etiquette on SO is to accept it as _the_ answer to your question. This way, people with the same problem can see what the proper solution was, even down the line.

Comment: lazy = non-greedy or minimal, in Python regex terminology. I usually understand lazy as meaning "evaluate only when necessary", which doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Thank you so much. So the better one maybe`http://[^\s]*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)` of `http://\S*?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)`?

Comment: @LiuHao: I've added a regex that'll do what you want, plus a few extra things.